# Changing Sitecore Cookie Config as HttpOnly

Tags: cookies, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm new to Sitecore, for my new Project, I need to make a few customizations in cookie creation.

I just found that with a custom processor, I can change existing cookies HttpOnly vale as 'true'.  But is there any way to force the Sitecore to create cookies with HttpOnly as 'true'? I'm using Sitecore 10 version.

Config Patch

```
<processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"
     type="MySCProject.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.CookieProcessor, MySCProject.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" />
```

Custom Processor

```
    public class CookieProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["shell#lang"];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Sitecore cookies]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `httpOnlyCookies` attribute to true in the  element within the `web.config` file under webroot.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

and make sure if it is compatible with all your requriments.

Comment: This does not appear to work for the shell#lang cookie.